# Difference between Static binding and Dynamic binding of Array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-binding, static-binding

I've just read through all the search result about the same topic I'm asking right now in stackoverflow and it's not really answer my curiosity.But here's the thing.

**The Question**

1.)From what i know , static binding means it's set during compile time and it's there during runtime whereas for dynamic binding means it's set during runtime.

2.)So the book i read introduce about dynamic array , it mentions dynamic array size could be set during runtime.Which is done in this way.

**The Code**

```
int size;
cin >> size;
int * pz = new int [size]; // dynamic binding, size set at run time
delete [] pz; // free memory when finished
```

3.)In this code the book mention dynamic array size could be set during runtime.So out out curiosity i try this.

**The Code**

```
int size;
cin >> size;
int array[size];
//After the array declaraction i assign value to it to check whether it works or not.
```

4.)The code above works too , so i just curious what so special about dynamic array since normal static array could did the same job.

5.)Is it because of dynamic array could free its memory during runtime whereas static can't that's what makes it so special??

*Thanks for spending time reading my question , do point out any mistake made by me.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your static array with dynamic size (called a variable length array, short VLA) only works thanks to a language extension in your compiler. It's a C99 thing, which isn't contained in the C++ standard, meaning it won't be portable.

The other obvious difference is that you can pass the pointer to the dynamic array somewhere else, save it somewhere, return it from a function, or in other words, have it **outlive the scope it was created in**. You can't do that with static arrays, as they are destroyed at the end of their scope.

Answer (score 2):

```
int size;
int array[size];
```

will throw a compile time failures saying **size is not a compile time constant or  expected constant expression**.

You declare arrays like these

`int array[5]`

or

```
const int size = 100;
int array[size];
```

when  you know the array size well ahead of time.

Otherwise you use the **new** and **delete []** approach.  I would recommended avoiding this construct altogether in favor of **std::vector**

Answer (score 1):

***early binding:-*** A language in which most binding are made during translation,early in the processing of a program is said to have early binding.
***Late binding:-*** language with late binding delay most binding until l execution time.

***early binding:-*** It is less flexible.
***Late binding:-*** It has more programming flexibility.

***early binding:-*** In this data is accept in only in declare data type
***Late binding:-*** In this variable can accept any type of data.

***early binding:-*** It is detect in correct type of the assignment.
***Late binding:-*** In this incorrect type of right side of assignment are not detect or error.

***early binding:-*** Type checking must be done at compile time.
***Late binding:-*** Type checking must be done at run time.

***early binding:-*** It user compiler or interpreter.
***Late binding:-*** Language that have late binding for variable are usually implemented using pure interpreter rather than compiler.